# How to Inherit $belongsTo of AppModel in Extended Model in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, inheritance, model, associations

In Cakephp,
I have used belongsTo in AppModel

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ModifiedBy' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'common_modified_by_user_id'
        )
    ); 
}
```

Now I also want to apply belongs to in UserModel

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'School' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'school_id'
        )
    );

}
```

But when i do so...it over rides the belongsTo of App model and on School data comes in the fetched array....

Please Help...

Comment: If you have this already resolved with the answer given, could you accept it? Or if it didn't give you a solution, post new details to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No automatic merging of associations

Other than the `$actsAs` and `$findMethods` variables, association configurations are not being merged automatically, you'll have to do that on your own.

It should be rather simple to solve, using `Object::_mergeVars()` in your `User` models constructor should do the trick:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    $parent = get_parent_class($this);
    $this->_mergeVars(array('belongsTo'), $parent);

    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}
```

ps. you might want to have a look at [**behaviors**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html), they might be the better option for your needs.

Comment: How about putting this constructor function in `appModel.php`?? Logically it should work without problem but is there a downside that I'm overlooking?

Comment: except that a table in a database might exist without these colunms throwing exceptions...anything other than that?